# cgi-binのサブディレクトリのcgiが動作しない

Tags: apache, perl

Perl の CGI です。

```
cgi-bin/hello.cgi
```

だと動作するのですが、サブディレクトリを置いて

```
cgi-bin/folder/hello.cgi
```

という感じにすると

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /cgi-bin/0_search/hello.cgi on this server.
```

と表示されて動作がしません。
folder と cgi のパーミッションは 755 です。

hello.cgi の中身

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

print "Content-type: text/html \n\n";
print "Hello";
```

Apache のバージョン確認

```
[vagrant@localhost 0_search]$ httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
Server built:   May 12 2016 10:27:23
[vagrant@localhost 0_search]$
```

CentOS7 です。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SELinuxが有効になっていたら無効にしてみてください。

production環境で運用するときにSELinuxを有効にしたい場合はその時点で判らないところを別途質問たててください。

追記：
cgi-binが/var/www/cgi-bin だとして

```
# ls -Z /var/www/cgi-bin/folder/
```

の結果、該当ファイルが「httpd_sys_script_exec_t」になっていないからでしょう。

```
# chcon system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_script_exec_t /var/www/cgi-bin -R
または
# semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_script_exec_t "/var/www/cgi-bin(/.*)?"
```

を行い、cgi-bin ディレクトリ配下に対して httpd_sys_script_exec_t を設定してやれば質問に記載のスクリプトであればSELinuxが有効でも動くと思います。

SELinux有効にしてcgiなどで色々やろうとするとファイル(ディレクトリ)へのラベル(タイプ？)の設定がかなり邪魔臭いです。ちょっと複雑な構成のものになると何がどうなってるのか解らなくなって苦労します。

こんなの↓があるくらいなので

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/ja-JP/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Managing_Confined_Services/sect-Managing_Confined_Services-The_Apache_HTTP_Server-Types.html

> httpd_unconfined_script_exec_t
>   このタイプのラベルを付けたスクリプトは SELinux の保護なしで実行されます。 このタイプの使用は、 これ以外の手段を試したがいずれもうまくいかない複雑なスクリプトを使用する場合に限ってください。 httpd に対して SELinux の保護をオフにする、 またはシステム全体に対して SELinux の保護をオフにするよりは、 このタイプを使用した方がよいでしょう。

Comment: ちなみに私のところでは、素のCentOS 7でSELinuxを特に設定せず（有効にしたまま）、`cgi-bin/hello.cgi`を動かしたとき、`cgi-bin/folder/hello.cgi`も同じように動きました。

Comment: 'sudo setenforce 0'でSELinuxを一時的に無効化すれば無事に動きました。ありがとうございます。有効になっていても動くのは何が違うのでしょうね…。

Comment: SELinux有効時のファイル(ディレクトリ)へのラベル設定についてあまり詳しくはないですが概要だけ追記しました

Comment: ラベルが問題で`cgi-bin/folder/hello.cgi`がダメな場合、`cgi-bin/hello.cgi`はなぜ大丈夫なのかなと。考えられるのは、`cgi-bin/hello.cgi`と`cgi-bin/folder/hello.cgi`とで、ファイルを配備した方法が違う場合でしょうか。まあ、原因を追求する前にSELinuxをオフにしておくという方針もアリと思います。